# Why didn't the British consider the USS President's attempted flight as a fake surrender?

Tags: naval, war-of-1812, international-law

In the War of 1812, [the USS *President* was captured by the Royal Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capture_of_USS_President).

Wikipedia gives the final actions of the day:

> *President* ceased fire at 7:58 pm and hoisted a light in her rigging, indicating that she had surrendered ... Following the standard practice, *Endymion* ceased fire and hove to for repairs once President had surrendered. *Endymion* could not immediately take possession of her prize, as she had no usable boats; Decatur took advantage of the situation, despite having struck, and made off to escape at 8:30 pm. Endymion hastily completed repairs and resumed the chase at 8:52 pm. At 9:05, *Pomone* and *Tenedos* came up with the heavily damaged *President*, unaware that she had already struck. Pomone fired two ineffective broadsides (there was minimal damage to *President*'s starboard side) into her, following which Decatur hailed to say that he had surrendered. Shortly afterwards, Captain Lumley of *Pomone* took possession of *President*.

By attempting to escape, had the *President* not faked a surrender? This would IMHO qualify as [perfidy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfidy) under modern laws of war, and as a war crime. Yet Wikipedia's article on [Stephen Decatur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Decatur) (who was commanding the USS *President*) indicates the British weren't offended at all:

> Soon *Majestic* caught up with the British fleet. Decatur, now dressed in full dress uniform, boarded *Majestic* and surrendered his sword to Captain Hayes. Hayes in a gesture of admiration returned the sword to Decatur saying that he was "proud in returning the sword of an officer, who had defended his ship so nobly." Before taking possession of *President*, Hayes allowed Decatur to return to his ship to perform burial services for the officers and seamen who had died in the engagement. He was also allowed to write a letter to his wife.

Why would the British not be offended?

Comment: Your question  asserts that it *was* a "fake surrender" (merely asking why the British weren't incensed by it). Unaware of the engagement in question, I expected to read something like using the "fake surrender" to fire upon the enemy once they let down their guard -- which USS *President* didn't do. They attempted to *escape*, which is the right, nay the duty of a POW if given the chance. Obviously the British thought in similar veins, so there was nothing "fake" about the surrender, or dishonorable in the attempt to escape. Perhaps re-phrase title and question in a more neutral way?

Comment: @DevSolar you think it's not a fake surrender? The perfidy article linked gives as the first example: "(a) The feigning of an intent to negotiate under a flag of truce or of a surrender" - it doesn't distinguish whether the person surrendering is firing weapons.

Comment: The *British* present that day apparently didn't think it was a fake surrender, and I guess they were more of an authority on the etiquette of the time than either of us. Your question thusly boils down to, "why *wasn't* it considered a fake surrender", a much less confrontational (and less contentious) question to ask.

Comment: Just as @DevSolar explains, it simply was **not** an example of a "fake surrender".  Questions on *History* with massive assumptions in the question title, are confusing.  On say the *Politics* site (aka "Americans argue about Trump site" :/ ) it's natural that people put massive assumptions in the question title, because, most QA on that site are just agitprop, not actual investigations.  Here on *History* I'd say it's just confusing.  (I assume nobody is currently exercised about the details of that 1812 naval engagement :)  )

Comment: (When I say "it simply was **not** an example of a fake surrender" I mean (A) it wasn't and (B) it's not given as an example of a fake surrender in the literature (many such events are)  :O

Comment: @Allure Nothing in the story suggests that there was any _feigning of intent_. It's just that the situation changed post-surrender. I don't see any controversy here. Basically, faking a surrender isn't the same as later "unsurrendering". Otherwise no prisoner anywhere would ever escape.

Comment: @DevSolar I don't see any difference but edited the title anyway. If you still find it not neutral, feel free to edit it (and the question) yourself.

Comment: @Allure even your article, which doesn't really apply being too modern, states "It is prohibited to **kill, injure or capture an adversary** by resort to perfidy." So, if *President* would feign surrender and then capture the boarding party, this would have been a war crime by modern standards and a dishonourable act at the time. Simply trying to escape would not be a crime now, and apparently was seen as a fair play by the British.

Comment: @IMil read one more sentence. "Acts inviting the confidence of an adversary to lead him to believe that he is entitled to, or is obliged to accord, protection under the rules of international law applicable in armed conflict, with intent to betray that confidence, shall constitute perfidy." Surrendering makes one a PoW, and therefore protection under the rules of international law applicable in armed conflict. Escaping at once is intent to betray that confidence.

Comment: @Allure do you expect the British and US Navies in 1812 AD to adhere to the letter of the treaty signed in 1977?

Comment: @IMil no, I don't. What's your point? Remember, you claimed that this is not a crime now, and my response is explicitly directed at that.

Comment: Why did you cross-post this on Quora (and use the wrong tag)?

Comment: @RonJohn I didn't. If someone did, it's not me.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I think a key part of this is whether the *President*'s captain intentionally faked the initial surrender. Since Decatur could not know the exact condition of the *Endymion* but was well aware of the condition of his own vessel (and the increasing proximity of the rest of the British squadron), I think he genuinely intended to surrender his ship.

Once he saw that the *Endymion* was in a similar condition and also was not making any obvious moves to send a prize crew to take control of his ship (as the *Endymion* had lost her boats), he saw a chance to escape. The position is similar to a POW on the battlefield who suddenly finds that his guards are looking the other way and makes a run for it. So it wasn't as if the surrender had been a ruse from the outset.

Also since the British ultimately captured the *President* a short while later (with no further loss of life), there was little time for any resentment to build on the British side and they had their prize (money).

As a contrast, at the [Battle of Lissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Lissa_(1811)) in 1811, a similar situation involved the French frigate *Flore*. The ship had suffered from heavy damage in the battle and had apparently surrendered. However, the smaller British squadron was in no position to take immediate possession of the prize. The *Flore* took advantage of this to set sail for the French harbour on Lesina.

The key difference between the two situations is that the *Flore* indicated to the British ships that she passed that she had surrendered (and was effectively a non-combatant) to get by them and successfully escape.

> In surrendering and then escaping, the officers of Flore had breached an informal rule of naval conflict under which a ship that voluntarily struck its flag submitted to an opponent in order to prevent continued loss of life among its crew. Flore had been able to pass unmolested through the British squadron only because she was recognised to have surrendered, and to abuse this custom in this way was considered, in the Royal Navy especially, to be a dishonourable act.

So it was the actions of the ship in repeatedly abusing the condition of surrender (quite possibly exacerbated by the loss of the ship as a prize) that upset the British in this earlier case.

Answer (score 22):

Courtesy of a comment below by [Samuel Russel](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/876/samuel-russell), this particular salient point must be borne in mind while reading the following:

> Surrender needs to be effectively received. The lack of efficacy was obvious to Endymion: President was capable of flight.

---

To apply modern rules of war to events of two hundred years ago is absurd.

Further, it has always been the case that much more liberal use of *ruses of war* is acceptable in naval warfare than land warfare.

In 1863, in preparation for the Emancipation Proclamation, Lincoln commissioned the [Lieber Code](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/19th_century/lieber.asp#art86), which were subsequently published as  general Rules of Engagement for all Union forces. Article 101 of that states:

> **Art. 101**
>
> While deception in war is admitted as a just and necessary means of hostility, and is consistent with honorable warfare, the common law of war allows even capital punishment for clandestine or treacherous attempts to injure an enemy, because they are so dangerous, and it is difficult to guard against them.

Under this statement, much closer to general standards of 1812 than today's Hague and Geneva Conventions, *perfidy* involves "*clandestine or treacherous attempts to injure an enemy*" and not mere deception.

Comment: Surrender needs to be effectively received.  The lack of efficacy was obvious to Endymion: President was capable of flight.

Comment: @SamuelRussell: Brilliant phrasing of what I was trying to get at.

Comment: The second sentence here is an excellent point.  Indeed more generally, the "rules" of naval warfare (in the past, even the present) are just generally "strange, bizarre and basically completely whacky to an outsider."

Comment: And “rules of war” is a nonsensical concept in general.  War is either an uncivilized offense, or a defense.  And in defense, one does what one must.

Comment: @WGroleau: Not true. Read the [1863 Lieber Code, aka General Order 100](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/19th_century/lieber.asp) commissioned by Lincoln. Nations have always conducted their military operations according to certain customs in general agreement with their enemies.

Comment: The fact that some combatants show some restraint doesn't change the barbarity of the whole thing.

Comment: I'm sure you'd feel the same way if you were the one fighting the war, and might actually be subjected with the things that are agreed to be war crimes.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens please feel free to edit it into your answer! :D

Comment: @SamuelRussell: Good idea - done. Thank you again for the great phrasing.

Comment: @WGroleau All war is and must be barbarous by modern Western standards, but there are degrees of barbarity and war governed by treaties or custom is a very different matter than the unconditional warfare still sometimes seen.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman: Western Europe, and its derivative cultures, learned a painful lesson during the 150 years ending 1648 that the rest of the world has not. Unfortunately, Western cultures have lost the will to fight fire with fire.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Oh, please. Argueing "lessons learned" with the Peace of Westphalia in one sentence, and calling for an eye for an eye in the next?

Comment: @DevSolar: Read the [Lieber Code](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/19th_century/lieber.asp)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: What for?

Comment: @WGroleau it's telling that chemical weapons were not used in WW2 even when one or the other side was close to collapse while defending in a total war, and a bunch of other "rules of war" were mostly followed despite that - and noone really regrets following them.

Comment: @Peteris: I have read that Hitler had a passionate dislike for poison gas, and refused to contemplate their use in combat - ironic considering his willingness to use it elsewhere.